# how to get around blocking behavior of gtk event loop in python

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk2

I've reduced my problem down to this simple example script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import hello
from threading import Thread

def myfunc():

        hello.HelloWorld().main()

t = Thread(target=myfunc)
t.start()

print '\nstill running ???'
```

The problem is I'm trying to find someway to get around the blocking behavior of the gtk event loop.  Is this possible?  As you can see, even if I call the class from a separate thread the event loop blocks further progress in the main script ("still running ???" is not printed until the gtk application is closed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [threading best practice for pyGTK](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq20.006.htp). GTK should be used in the main thread, but still, I agree that is strange.

I've tried the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import gtk
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


def myfunc():
    w = gtk.Window()
    l = gtk.Label()
    w.add(l)
    w.show_all()
    w.connect("destroy", lambda _: gtk.main_quit())
    gtk.main()

def myfunc2():
    sleep (3)

t = Thread(target=myfunc)
#t = Thread(target=myfunc2)
t.start()

print '\nstill running ???'
```

And what is worse, is that almost always the message will be printed after closing the app, but *sometimes* it appears before. So, there's a strange behavior here.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but since `hello.HelloWorld().main()` is within the function `myfunc` which is the target of the thread created isn't `hello.HelloWorld().main()` created in the new thread?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, read a bit quickly. Don't really know why, but calling `gtk.main()` in the thread indeed blocks the main thread, whereas a `sleep(10) won't. However, GTK is not thread safe, so you shouldn't try to do some graphical stuff in a thread. You should put your print in a thread and keep the GTK stuff in the main thread. I modify my post to reflect that.

Comment: thank you for the link.  I had not seen that page and I was not aware of many of the facets involved with threads in pygtk. I was starting to get the feeling that I shouldn't be launching gtk in a thread.  Thanks for confirming.  This is all new, lots to learn.

Comment: Be aware also that this is all GTK2-specific, and that python bindings for GTK3 use pyGObject instead. More info at: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html